click event in angular 18 doesn't work in mobile devices
I have a problem on a reservation website. On desktop devices, such as desktops, laptops, and even mobile devices in "desktop mode," users can select their seats, which automatically changes the color of the selected seats to black (indicating that they are selected). Other seat colors are white (available), yellow (reserved), and a custom image for seats that are occupied (not available).
The issue occurs on mobile devices without "desktop mode." When a seat is selected, it does not immediately change to black. Instead, it only changes color after the user taps outside the seat or on another seat. Once the user taps elsewhere on the screen or selects another seat, the original seat turns black. Is there a solution for this? I tried using touchstart and touchend events, but they made the issue worse.
I use Angular 18
The HTML is
<tbody class="tbody">                 
  <tr *ngFor="let row of seats; let rowIndex = index" class="row">                     
  <td *ngFor="let seat of row" 
      [ngClass]="{
         'seat': existSeat(seat),
         'seat-available': existSeat(seat) && isAvailable(seat),
         'selected-seat': existSeat(seat) && isSelected(seat.fila, seat.butaca),  
         'reservated-seat': existSeat(seat) && isReservated(seat),
         'paid-seat': existSeat(seat) && isPaid(seat) && !mySeat(seat),
         'seat-user': existSeat(seat) && mySeat(seat),
         'empty-seat':!existSeat(seat) || isDisabledSeat(seat)
         }"                      
       title="{{ seat.butaca }}"
       (click)="existSeat(seat) && isAvailable(seat) && toggleSeatSelection(seat.fila, seat.butaca, seat.tipo)">
   </td>
   <td class="row-number">
       {{ rowIndex + 1 }}
   </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>

I tried adding other events, like touchstart and touchend, for mobile devices, but the problem got worse. When I use those events, the selected seats are not properly counted, and the behavior becomes unpredictable.
I am also using flags to indicate to Angular that the device is a mobile one, like:
isMobileDevice(): boolean {
   return /Mobi|Android|iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent); 
}

None of these attemps work for me. So I eliminated these changes.
Phone Demonstration video
Desktop Demonstration video
